# The correct way to license Window 8.1 on a VMWare image

Tags: windows-8.1, vmware-fusion, license

I've been tasked with getting some beta customers up and running with our software which runs on Windows.  The target customers are using Macs.

The approach I'm taking is buying them VMWare Fusion licenses and shipping them a pre-configured image of Windows with our software already installed on a USB drive.

I activated the image with one of our BizSpark Windows licenses, just so I could move forward.

My question is...what's the best way to deal with the Windows license?

Can I just buy additional Windows licenses?
Or do I need to buy them and change the activation code on each image?

Right now, there is only 4 images but I have a feeling that they will ask for more.

Should I look into a Volume license?

Any advice would be welcome.

Comment: Use Sysprep to your advantage.